# Apache ofbiz "build.xml does not exist!" error

Tags: build, ant, ofbiz

I'm trying to reset my admin password using a guide that uses Ant.

However when I try to change the password using the `ant` command

[image]

I get the error

```
Buildfle: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get round this?

Comment: No offense, but this is possibly the most ridiculous question I've ever seen on stackoverflow. First of all, you typed `ls` in that location and you can clearly see there is no build.xml present. Either you're in the wrong directory or the file was deleted. Secondly, you took a photo of the console output with your damn phone lol. Normally people get yelled at for taking screenshots instead of posting text, but here I am looking through several inches of real, physical air molecules while trying to diagnose your problem. I'm rating this question up because it's so amazing. Thanks, harry.

Answer (score 1):

You are using OFBiz 16.11.03 which is using Gradle as the build system instead of Ant like in the previous versions. Please refer to the README.md in the projects root for comprehensive help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using 17.12.03 version and It gave:

```
Buildfle: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

So I switched to 16.11.01, and lucky I was blessed with same obstruction again.

So I got my hands dirty and Finally Installed it by following steps:

0. Make the **Apache_Ofbiz** folder as CURRENT DIRECTORY.
1. "./gradle/init-gradle-wrapper.sh" (it may take some time depending upon internet connection)
2. Make sure you have java version < 14 (as Gradle still does not support java 14) if not downgrade it with following steps:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
    sudo update-alternatives --config javac
    select jdk8
    sudo update-alternatives --config java
    select jre8
    now java -version to confirm changes
   ```
3. "./gradlew ofbiz" (it may take some time depending upon internet connection)
4. **Done**
   Just visit https://localhost:8443/ordermgr or go through **README**

Now I got the latest version install by following above steps.